# How can I create a VPN server with SoftEther and connect it with Azure site-to-site?

Tags: windows, vpn, softether

I have a Windows server and I want to create a VPN server with SoftEther to connect it with Azure. I have the Azure side (subnets, a Local Virtual Network, a Virtual Network Gateway and a Connection) that asks three things: the IP of the on-premises network gateway, on-premises address space in CIDR notation, and the PreShared Key (PSK).

I previously successfully connected AWS with Azure with a tutorial but I couldn't replicate the configuration locally as I'm not sure of the steps to follow with SoftEther and the Windows configuration. The goal is to be able to understand how to configure an on-premises network for a site-to-site VPN connection with Azure.

I ticked the "Enable EtherIP / L2TPv3 over IPsec Server Function" option and set up the PSK but apart from that I have no clue on what to do next as I'm starting in the networking field.